# Where to insert a loop/timer?

Tags: python

I need to insert a loop to ensure that the following runs and appends to the txt file every hour and I am stuck on where to properly put the loop.

thanks in advance.

```
from datetime import datetime   
from threading import Timer

def log(self, LOG_TAG, LOG_MESSAGE):
    print('{}: {}'.format(LOG_TAG, LOG_MESSAGE))
    now = datetime.utcnow()
    print(now)
    year = now.year
    day = now.day
    month = now.month
    print('year = {}, month = {}, day = {}'.format(year, month, day)) 


    with open('log_{}_{}_{}.txt'.format(year, month, day), 'a+') as f:
        f.write('{} \t {}: {} \n'.format(now, LOG_TAG, LOG_MESSAGE)) 
                 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    log = Spider_Log()
    tag = 'SPIDERLOG'
    log.log(tag, 'test2')
```

Comment: Although this can be done in Python, consider avoiding the timer inside of a long-running Python script and simply scheduling the script to execute every hour with a task scheduler or cron job.

Comment: having some trouble importing schedule to my .py

Answer (score 0):

You can use a different thread to keep track of time. Once the set interval of time has lapsed, it would trigger an event. Another thread can wait for this event and do the part of printing to the log file. You can refer to the following code -

```
import threading, time
from _datetime import datetime


def thread_to_keep_time(event):
    while True:
        #Set it to 10 seconds for testing. 
        time.sleep(10)
        event.set()

def thread_to_trigger(event):
    print("Waiting for event")
    while True:
        if event.wait():
            now = datetime.now()
            print('Print log at ' , now)
            timer_event.clear()


timer_event = threading.Event()
threading.Thread(target=thread_to_keep_time, args=[timer_event]).start()
threading.Thread(target=thread_to_trigger, args=[timer_event]).start()

# wait for all threads to exit
for t in threading.enumerate():
    if t != threading.current_thread():
        t.join()
```

Comment: You can call your log function when the event is triggered, something like this -
def thread_to_trigger(event):
    print("Waiting for event")
    while True:
        if event.wait():
            log = Spider_Log()
     tag = 'SPIDERLOG'
     log.log(tag, 'test2')